# independence - joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ random variables with $Y$ real valued. I was wondering if any inequality of the type: 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)] \leq g \left[\sup_{\displaystyle s \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}[f(X,s)] \right]
\end{equation}

exists, where $g$ is some function. It seems very wrong at first sight, but I was wondering if you knew something of this type.